# .HTACCESS can't accept $2

Tags: php, .htaccess

I have this .htaccess code to rewrite file

```
RewriteRule ^forum/(.*)/(.*)$   "/forum.main.php?forum=$1&type=$2"
```

Everything works before $2 , $2 cannot work .. It just don't accept it , why ?

Thanks.

Comment: You're not supposed to enclose the replacement path in quotes.

Comment: there's nothing wrong with this, and works when I test it: http://htaccess.madewithlove.be/

Comment: .. right, except the quotes, but that would just add quotes to the redirect, e.g. example.com/"/forum.main.php?forum=x&type=y"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The regular expression might be too greedy. The following two would be completely consumed by the first capture group:

```
 forum/blargh/          # $1 = "blargh"
 forum/blargh/zoid/     # $1 = "blargh/zoid"
```

You might want to try and substitute `(.*)` for `(.*?)`, or even "everything but a slash":

```
RewriteRule ^forum/([^/]+)/([^/]+) ...
```

Comment: What? Why? Please unaccept and update your question as to how it "didn't work", which of the above solutions you tried, etc.